# XSLT 1.0, Using Identity Transform, with multiple templates fails to match

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Wow, I haven't asked this many questions since, intro to programming some 15 years ago, this XSLT stuff is kicking me!  I've been learning to work with Identity Transform, to take a string and break it into nodes based on a delimiter.  Which I have working as expected, but when I combine it with the rest of my logic it breaks. I'm thinking it has to do with my selectors on the elements themselves.  I'm just proud of myself that I figured out a working basic example of Identity transform.   I've been working and learning through phases, with the original starting here. [XSLT 1.0 - Output Count of Value Uniqueness in a Node with Vanilla XSLT 1.0 or PHP XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65419245/xslt-1-0-output-count-of-value-uniqueness-in-a-node-with-vanilla-xslt-1-0-or-p/65419703#65419703)   I think selectors and order of operations are going to be the next things I need to wrap my head around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Source Data ***EDITED*** Don't use, as I supplied flawed data originally, and added updated data below.

```
<root>
  <part>
    <partNumber>33020780</partNumber>
    <punctuatedPartNumber>3302-0780</punctuatedPartNumber>
    <partStatusDescription>STANDARD</partStatusDescription>
    <partDescription>Women's Hooligan Glove - Black - 2XL</partDescription>
    <unitOfMeasure>Pair</unitOfMeasure>
    <brandName>ICON</brandName>
    <supplierNumber></supplierNumber>
    <specialInstructions/>
    <baseDealerPrice>15.0000</baseDealerPrice>
    <yourDealerPrice>15.0000</yourDealerPrice>
    <baseRetailPrice>30.0000</baseRetailPrice>
    <originalRetailPrice>30.0000</originalRetailPrice>
    <partImage>http://asset.lemansnet.com/z/L0UvOS8zL0U5M0JDMzM4LUNEMDAtNDhGNi1CMjQzLTJCM0U3ODBCQzU0NCwvRC85LzEvRDkxQUQ1ODQtQjU0Ny00MTYzLUIxNDgtMzk3MTMwOEU2N0U5</partImage>
    <productId>1967508881</productId>
    <productName>Women's Hooligan™ Gloves</productName>
    <productImage>http://asset.lemansnet.com/z/bWVkaWEvYzY1Y2JiYzctYTk4OC00OTY0LWJlYTEtNzYzZDFiYmQ4NzBlLC9FLzkvMy9FOTNCQzMzOC1DRDAwLTQ4RjYtQjI0My0yQjNFNzgwQkM1NDQsejJodWhwWVN1cGc=</productImage>
    <bullet1>Durable nylon/synthetic suede construction</bullet1>
    <bullet2>AxSuede Laredo palm</bullet2>
    <bullet3>Thermoplastic knuckle armor for durable, flexible protection</bullet3>
    <bullet4>Ram air finger inserts help keep hands cool</bullet4>
    <bullet5>Snap secures gloves together when not in use</bullet5>
    <bullet6/>
    <bullet7/>
    <bullet8/>
    <bullet9/>
    <bullet10/>
    <bullet11/>
    <bullet12/>
    <bullet13/>
    <bullet14/>
    <bullet15/>
    <bullet16/>
    <bullet17/>
    <bullet18/>
    <bullet19/>
    <bullet20/>
    <bullet21/>
    <bullet22/>
    <bullet23/>
    <bullet24/>
  </part>
  <part>
    <partNumber>33020783</partNumber>
    <punctuatedPartNumber>3302-0783</punctuatedPartNumber>
    <partStatusDescription>STANDARD</partStatusDescription>
    <partDescription>Women's Hooligan Glove - Pink - Medium</partDescription>
    <unitOfMeasure>Pair</unitOfMeasure>
    <brandName>ICON</brandName>
    <supplierNumber></supplierNumber>
    <specialInstructions/>
    <baseDealerPrice>15.0000</baseDealerPrice>
    <yourDealerPrice>15.0000</yourDealerPrice>
    <baseRetailPrice>30.0000</baseRetailPrice>
    <originalRetailPrice>30.0000</originalRetailPrice>
    <partImage>http://asset.lemansnet.com/z/L0UvRi8zL0VGMzE4NzU3LTZCNDAtNDUyNi1CMjY3LTRBMzYzNTI2RkU1RSwvMC9EL0MvMERDQ0NCQTktMEVEOC00QzI0LThBRDYtOTRDNzVCQUU5NUVC</partImage>
    <productId>1967508881</productId>
    <productName>Women's Hooligan™ Gloves</productName>
    <productImage>http://asset.lemansnet.com/z/bWVkaWEvYzY1Y2JiYzctYTk4OC00OTY0LWJlYTEtNzYzZDFiYmQ4NzBlLC9FLzkvMy9FOTNCQzMzOC1DRDAwLTQ4RjYtQjI0My0yQjNFNzgwQkM1NDQsejJodWhwWVN1cGc=</productImage>
    <bullet1>Durable nylon/synthetic suede construction</bullet1>
    <bullet2>AxSuede Laredo palm</bullet2>
    <bullet3>Thermoplastic knuckle armor for durable, flexible protection</bullet3>
    <bullet4>Ram air finger inserts help keep hands cool</bullet4>
    <bullet5>Snap secures gloves together when not in use</bullet5>
    <bullet6/>
    <bullet7/>
    <bullet8/>
    <bullet9/>
    <bullet10/>
    <bullet11/>
    <bullet12/>
    <bullet13/>
    <bullet14/>
    <bullet15/>
    <bullet16/>
    <bullet17/>
    <bullet18/>
    <bullet19/>
    <bullet20/>
    <bullet21/>
    <bullet22/>
    <bullet23/>
    <bullet24/>
  </part>
</root>
```

Working Identity Transform

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="partDescription" name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' - '"/>
        <xsl:param name="keys" select="'short_name,color,size'"/>
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before($keys, ',')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="keys" select="substring-after($keys, ',')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Broken Full Example, when I say broken the result is just `<items/>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="part-by-product" match="part" use="productId" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Transform Data  -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Parse Description as Keys  -->
    <xsl:template match="partDescription" name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' - '"/>
        <xsl:param name="keys" select="'short_name,color,size'"/>
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before($keys, ',')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="keys" select="substring-after($keys, ',')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:element name="items">
            <xsl:for-each select="part[supplierNumber/text() and partStatusDescription != 'DISCONTINUED']">
                <xsl:element name="item">
                    
                    <!-- finish -->
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Black')">
                            <finish>Black</finish>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Flat Back')">
                            <finish>Flat Back</finish>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Chrome')">
                            <finish>Chrome</finish>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    
                    <!-- size -->
                    <xsl:call-template name="find-size">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="partDescription"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>

                    <!-- Check if a Product should be configurable -->
                    <xsl:copy-of select="partNumber | productId"/>
                    <!-- check productId uniqueness -->
                    <xsl:if test="count(key('part-by-product', productId)) > 1">
                        <configurableId>
                            <xsl:value-of select="productId"/>
                        </configurableId>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:element name="name">
                         <xsl:value-of select="concat(brandName,' ',productName)"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <punctuatedPartNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="punctuatedPartNumber"/>
                    </punctuatedPartNumber>
                     <xsl:element name="is_in_stock">
                        <xsl:if test="partStatusDescription = 'STANDARD'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="partStatusDescription != 'STANDARD'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                        </xsl:if>    
                    </xsl:element>
                    <partDescription>
                        <xsl:value-of select="partDescription"/>
                    </partDescription>
                    <unitOfMeasure>
                        <xsl:value-of select="unitOfMeasure"/>
                    </unitOfMeasure>
                    <brandName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="brandName"/>
                    </brandName>
                    <supplierNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="supplierNumber"/>
                    </supplierNumber>
                    <specialInstructions>
                        <xsl:value-of select="specialInstructions"/>
                    </specialInstructions>
                    <xsl:element name="price">
                        <xsl:value-of select="(originalRetailPrice * 100) div 100"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="special_price">
                        <xsl:if test="baseRetailPrice  &lt; originalRetailPrice">
                            <xsl:value-of select="baseRetailPrice"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <partImage>
                        <xsl:value-of select="partImage"/>
                    </partImage>
                    <productName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="productName"/>
                    </productName>
                    <productImage>
                        <xsl:value-of select="productImage"/>
                    </productImage>
                    <bullet1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="bullet1"/>
                    </bullet1>
                    <bullet2>
                        <xsl:value-of select="bullet2"/>
                    </bullet2>
                    <bullet3>
                        <xsl:value-of select="bullet3"/>
                    </bullet3>
                    <bullet4>
                        <xsl:value-of select="bullet4"/>
                    </bullet4>

                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="find-size">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(translate($token, '123456789', '000000000'), '0')">
                <size>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
                </size>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
                <!-- recursive call -->
                <xsl:call-template name="find-size">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***************************** EDITED BELOW ******************************

UPDATED DATA SAMPLE

I provided sample data, that would have never worked on accident, which also explains why I only received the original node element.  However, even after fixing my stupid mistake, my combination of codes does not work

```
<root>
  <part>
    <partNumber>33020576</partNumber>
    <punctuatedPartNumber>3302-0576</punctuatedPartNumber>
    <partStatusDescription>STANDARD</partStatusDescription>
    <partDescription>Stella SP-8 V2 Gloves - Black/White/Pink - Large</partDescription>
    <unitOfMeasure>Pair</unitOfMeasure>
    <brandName>ALPINESTARS (ROAD)</brandName>
    <supplierNumber>3518317-1239-L</supplierNumber>
    <specialInstructions/>
    <baseDealerPrice>68.0000</baseDealerPrice>
    <yourDealerPrice>68.0000</yourDealerPrice>
    <baseRetailPrice>99.9500</baseRetailPrice>
    <originalRetailPrice>99.9500</originalRetailPrice>
    <partImage>http://asset.lemansnet.com/z/L0EvRC84L0FEODhFNTI1LTBGRjItNEY3NC1CRTBDLTg4RkNBNjdCREVFQw==</partImage>
    <productId>0975297251</productId>
    <productName>Stella SP-8 V2 Leather Gloves</productName>
    <productImage>http://asset.lemansnet.com/z/LzcvMC9CLzcwQkJGNjJGLURDMDUtNDY0RC1BQ0YzLTQxN0FEQ0E3RDgwNCxtZWRpYS82OGFiOGQ5YS0wMDhiLTQ1NDctOGExMC1jZTBhNGU2MmUyNzQsbWVkaWEvYzZlODQwNDEtZTViMy00YTExLWJjYjUtODJiMDQ5NmI4OGZl</productImage>
    <bullet1>Tall, relaxed sport glove</bullet1>
    <bullet2>Premium, full-grain leather construction is durable and offers excellent abrasion resistance.</bullet2>
    <bullet3>An innovative microfiber and Polyurethane coated (PU) grip insert strategically position on palm and thumb for excellent levels of grip control and durability.</bullet3>
    <bullet4>Chassis is profiled for female specific fit and Alpinestars’ exclusive ergonomic stretch insert between palm and thumb offers improved range of hand movement and greater sensitivity while operating the bike controls.</bullet4>
    <bullet5>Incorporates premium quality suede palm and landing reinforcement for grip, control and durability.</bullet5>
    <bullet6>Alpinestars’ patented third and fourth finger bridge prevents seam failure and finger separation in the event of a slide.</bullet6>
    <bullet7>Excellent repeated impact performance offered by an advanced over-molded polymer knuckle protector.</bullet7>
    <bullet8>Ethylene vinyl acetate (EVA) foam padding reinforcements on thumb, wrist, back of hand, finger and palm for comfort and abrasion performance.</bullet8>
    <bullet9>Perforated leather cuff, plus perforated finger sidewalls for superb breathability.</bullet9>
    <bullet10>Velcro cuff closure, plus elasticized wrist design for secure, personalized fit.</bullet10>
    <bullet11>Pre-shaped fingers and external seams for comfort and exceptional feel.</bullet11>
    <bullet12>Printed and embroidered logos on wrist and fingers, plus heat stamped logo on knuckle.</bullet12>
    <bullet13>Touchscreen compatible fingertip on index finger for use with touch screen devices.</bullet13>
    <bullet14/>
    <bullet15/>
    <bullet16/>
    <bullet17/>
    <bullet18/>
    <bullet19/>
    <bullet20/>
    <bullet21/>
    <bullet22/>
    <bullet23/>
    <bullet24/>
  </part>
  <part>
    <partNumber>33020577</partNumber>
    <punctuatedPartNumber>3302-0577</punctuatedPartNumber>
    <partStatusDescription>STANDARD</partStatusDescription>
    <partDescription>Stella SP-8 V2 Gloves - Black/White/Pink - XL</partDescription>
    <unitOfMeasure>Pair</unitOfMeasure>
    <brandName>ALPINESTARS (ROAD)</brandName>
    <supplierNumber>3518317-1239-XL</supplierNumber>
    <specialInstructions/>
    <baseDealerPrice>68.0000</baseDealerPrice>
    <yourDealerPrice>68.0000</yourDealerPrice>
    <baseRetailPrice>99.9500</baseRetailPrice>
    <originalRetailPrice>99.9500</originalRetailPrice>
    <partImage>http://asset.lemansnet.com/z/L0EvRC84L0FEODhFNTI1LTBGRjItNEY3NC1CRTBDLTg4RkNBNjdCREVFQw==</partImage>
    <productId>0975297251</productId>
    <productName>Stella SP-8 V2 Leather Gloves</productName>
    <productImage>http://asset.lemansnet.com/z/LzcvMC9CLzcwQkJGNjJGLURDMDUtNDY0RC1BQ0YzLTQxN0FEQ0E3RDgwNCxtZWRpYS82OGFiOGQ5YS0wMDhiLTQ1NDctOGExMC1jZTBhNGU2MmUyNzQsbWVkaWEvYzZlODQwNDEtZTViMy00YTExLWJjYjUtODJiMDQ5NmI4OGZl</productImage>
    <bullet1>Tall, relaxed sport glove</bullet1>
    <bullet2>Premium, full-grain leather construction is durable and offers excellent abrasion resistance.</bullet2>
    <bullet3>An innovative microfiber and Polyurethane coated (PU) grip insert strategically position on palm and thumb for excellent levels of grip control and durability.</bullet3>
    <bullet4>Chassis is profiled for female specific fit and Alpinestars’ exclusive ergonomic stretch insert between palm and thumb offers improved range of hand movement and greater sensitivity while operating the bike controls.</bullet4>
    <bullet5>Incorporates premium quality suede palm and landing reinforcement for grip, control and durability.</bullet5>
    <bullet6>Alpinestars’ patented third and fourth finger bridge prevents seam failure and finger separation in the event of a slide.</bullet6>
    <bullet7>Excellent repeated impact performance offered by an advanced over-molded polymer knuckle protector.</bullet7>
    <bullet8>Ethylene vinyl acetate (EVA) foam padding reinforcements on thumb, wrist, back of hand, finger and palm for comfort and abrasion performance.</bullet8>
    <bullet9>Perforated leather cuff, plus perforated finger sidewalls for superb breathability.</bullet9>
    <bullet10>Velcro cuff closure, plus elasticized wrist design for secure, personalized fit.</bullet10>
    <bullet11>Pre-shaped fingers and external seams for comfort and exceptional feel.</bullet11>
    <bullet12>Printed and embroidered logos on wrist and fingers, plus heat stamped logo on knuckle.</bullet12>
    <bullet13>Touchscreen compatible fingertip on index finger for use with touch screen devices.</bullet13>
    <bullet14/>
    <bullet15/>
    <bullet16/>
    <bullet17/>
    <bullet18/>
    <bullet19/>
    <bullet20/>
    <bullet21/>
    <bullet22/>
    <bullet23/>
    <bullet24/>
  </part>
</root>
```

Comment: I don't see how the identity transformation is used if a template uses `for-each` instead of `apply-templates`. As for your sample data shown, I don't think there is any element selected with `<xsl:for-each select="part[supplierNumber/text()`, the shown `part` elements have empty `supplierNumber` elements.

Comment: Well, that was stupid of me, I didn't realize the test data I used, didn't contain those strings as 99% of the 180k items have it.  So fail on me, I'm going to add an edit, as even though I have correct sample data, I receive output, but not as I expect

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I fixed my stupid mistake, thank you for catching that... :face-palm:, however, I still don't get the expected result of <name>SP-8 V2 Gloves</name>
<color>Black/White/Yellow</color>
<size>3XL</size> from parsing the "partDescription" node.

Comment: If you want to have a template applied then make sure a level up you use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="partDescription"/>`, if you delegate all to an `xsl:for-each` and hardcoding the content inside you can't take advantage of template matching and the identity transformation.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, I wish I understood what you mean by this. :(.  I'm less than 10 hours into XSLT and doing a lot of guessing.

Comment: Reduce your task to micro steps you can manage and we can handle, I can't see why the first part called "Working Identity Transform" would work, it should give you an error trying to construct an XML element with an empty name on recursion I think. If not then show us a minimal working sample of input, XSLT and output you get there and then show us one change you want to add e.g. if you want to transform `root` to `items` I would suggest to add `<xsl:template match="/root"><items><xsl:apply-templates/></items></xsl:template>`. Don't throw in ten elements and then changes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, hi, thank you for your help.  Is there a good IDE for debugging XSLT?  Frankly put, I'm 100% guessing. I ended up in this situation because I choose micro-steps.  I had an entirely working template that handled everything except take the node <partDescription> and parse it into tokens, but I couldn't get it to work, so I tried tackling this task alone, and at the end I was successful, but every time I try to mix the two sets of logic, I always get a result as nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a major mistake, of filtering my data, and using sample data that would have been filtered out.  Then, learning, a key piece, that you have to be careful and thoughtful when you use "template matching" through my original use of the following

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

So, what I ended up having to do was to convert, from trying to match everything on the template level, and rather create an essential function, that took a node as a parameter and returned back the tokenized result.  While, I definitely know there are more efficient ways to accomplish my goal, and my XSLT code looks like it was written by a child, hopefully, someone can learn from my struggles.

**Shortened Version for ease of legibility.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="part-by-product" match="part" use="productId" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:element name="items">
            <xsl:for-each select="part[supplierNumber/text() and partStatusDescription != 'DISCONTINUED']">
                <xsl:element name="item">
                    
                    <!-- Call the custom template, and pass the node partDescription to the template -->
                    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="partDescription"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>

                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- A template that accepts a node with text passesd as a select  -->
    <xsl:template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' - '"/>
        <xsl:param name="keys" select="'name,color,size,configurable1,configurable2'"/>
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before($keys, ',')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="keys" select="substring-after($keys, ',')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My Expected Result Based on the completed example I will share after this**

```
<items>
    <item>
        <!-- This was the main goal this task, and what the above sample completes  -->
        <name>SP-8 V2 Gloves</name>
        <color>Black/White/Yellow</color>
        <size>3XL</size>
        <!-- The rest of the result that can be viewed by running the complete XSTL template -->
        <finish>Black</finish>
        <size>3XL</size>
        <partNumber>33012993</partNumber>
        <productId>0067377912</productId>
        <name>ALPINESTARS (ROAD) SP-8 V2 Gloves</name>
        <punctuatedPartNumber>3301-2993</punctuatedPartNumber>
        <is_in_stock>1</is_in_stock>
        <partDescription>SP-8 V2 Gloves - Black/White/Yellow - 3XL</partDescription>
        <unitOfMeasure>Pair</unitOfMeasure>
        <brandName>ALPINESTARS (ROAD)</brandName>
        <supplierNumber>3558317-125-3X</supplierNumber>
        <specialInstructions/>
        <price>99.95</price>
        <special_price/>
        <partImage>http://asset.lemansnet.com/z/LzkvNy9FLzk3RUYyQTg3LTM4QTItNDZEQy1CNzE2LThGMjNEQjQxNzgzOA==</partImage>
        <productName>SP-8 V2 Gloves</productName>
        <productImage>http://asset.lemansnet.com/z/L0UvRS9FL0VFRUEwQzRCLUZCRDktNDUzQS1CMTg3LUVCMTY2OUM5N0ZDQywvRi8yL0MvRjJDQjRERTMtQUM2MC00M0ZCLUFERDktMzE0NTA4QTIxQjcyLC8zLzAvNy8zMDdGRTEzMy0zMUFFLTQzQ0ItOTM3MC00NzY1OEI3RUM4MUEsbWVkaWEvNjhhYjhkOWEtMDA4Yi00NTQ3LThhMTAtY2UwYTRlNjJlMjc0LG1lZGlhL2M2ZTg0MDQxLWU1YjMtNGExMS1iY2I1LTgyYjA0OTZiODhmZQ==</productImage>
        <bullet1>Premium, full-grain leather construction is durable and offers excellent abrasion resistance</bullet1>
        <bullet2>An innovative microfiber and Polyurethane (PU) grip insert strategically position on palm and thumb</bullet2>
        <bullet3>Alpinestars’ exclusive ergonomic stretch insert between palm and thumb</bullet3>
        <bullet4>Premium quality suede palm and landing reinforcement.</bullet4>
    </item>
</items>
```

**Completed version based on my original example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="part-by-product" match="part" use="productId" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:element name="items">
            <xsl:for-each select="part[supplierNumber/text() and partStatusDescription != 'DISCONTINUED']">
                <xsl:element name="item">
                    
                    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="partDescription"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>

                    <!-- finish -->
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Black')">
                            <finish>Black</finish>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Flat Back')">
                            <finish>Flat Back</finish>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Chrome')">
                            <finish>Chrome</finish>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    
                    <!-- size -->
                    <xsl:call-template name="find-size">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="partDescription"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>

                    <!-- Check if a Product should be configurable -->
                    <xsl:copy-of select="partNumber | productId"/>
                    <!-- check productId uniqueness -->
                    <xsl:if test="count(key('part-by-product', productId)) > 1">
                        <configurableId>
                            <xsl:value-of select="productId"/>
                        </configurableId>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:element name="name">
                         <xsl:value-of select="concat(brandName,' ',productName)"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <punctuatedPartNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="punctuatedPartNumber"/>
                    </punctuatedPartNumber>
                     <xsl:element name="is_in_stock">
                        <xsl:if test="partStatusDescription = 'STANDARD'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="partStatusDescription != 'STANDARD'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                        </xsl:if>    
                    </xsl:element>
                    <partDescription>
                        <xsl:value-of select="partDescription"/>
                    </partDescription>
                    <unitOfMeasure>
                        <xsl:value-of select="unitOfMeasure"/>
                    </unitOfMeasure>
                    <brandName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="brandName"/>
                    </brandName>
                    <supplierNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="supplierNumber"/>
                    </supplierNumber>
                    <specialInstructions>
                        <xsl:value-of select="specialInstructions"/>
                    </specialInstructions>
                    <xsl:element name="price">
                        <xsl:value-of select="(originalRetailPrice * 100) div 100"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="special_price">
                        <xsl:if test="baseRetailPrice  &lt; originalRetailPrice">
                            <xsl:value-of select="baseRetailPrice"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <partImage>
                        <xsl:value-of select="partImage"/>
                    </partImage>
                    <productName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="productName"/>
                    </productName>
                    <productImage>
                        <xsl:value-of select="productImage"/>
                    </productImage>
                    <bullet1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="bullet1"/>
                    </bullet1>
                    <bullet2>
                        <xsl:value-of select="bullet2"/>
                    </bullet2>
                    <bullet3>
                        <xsl:value-of select="bullet3"/>
                    </bullet3>
                    <bullet4>
                        <xsl:value-of select="bullet4"/>
                    </bullet4>

                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Parse Description as Keys  -->
    <xsl:template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' - '"/>
        <xsl:param name="keys" select="'name,color,size,configurable1,configurable2'"/>
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before($keys, ',')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="keys" select="substring-after($keys, ',')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Size Template Engine -->
    <xsl:template name="find-size">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(translate($token, '123456789', '000000000'), '0')">
                <size>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
                </size>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
                <!-- recursive call -->
                <xsl:call-template name="find-size">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Consider tightening up the wordiness of your stylesheet and use a `part` template: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkq/1

Comment: I've been looking for a tool to do this online!!  You rock, while PHPStorm can process and run XSLT, it's error reporting and information is pretty minimal!  Thanks for sharing the information and helping me learn :)

Comment: No prob Rob! In fact, that site is maintained by the XSLT guru [@MartinHonnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen) whom you have been conversing with above. Happy coding!